# 2 different types of constructor invocation from copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, default-constructor, implicit-declaration

Consider the sample code below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class core
{
   public:
      core(const core& obj)
      {
         cout << "core copy ctor called\n";
      }
      core()
      {
         cout << "core default ctor called\n";
      }
};

class sample : public core
{
   public:
      sample()
      {
         cout << "sample default ctor called\n";
      }
#if 0
      sample(const sample& obj)
      {
         cout << "sample copy ctor called\n";
      }
#endif
};

int main()
{
   sample s1;
   sample s2 = s1; //Line1
   return 0;
}
```

**Type1: Copy constructor not declared explicitly for class sample**

(Type1 is shown in the code above. Then the copy constructor of class sample is implicitly generated by the compiler). 
When the statement, `Line1` is executed, first the copy constructor of `class core` is invoked, and then the copy constructor of `class sample` is invoked.

**Type2: Copy constructor defined explicitly for class sample**

When the statement, `Line1` is executed, first the default constructor of `class core` is invoked, and then the copy constructor of `class sample` is invoked.

**Question:**

Why is this difference in behavior for copy constructor as mentioned in Type1 and Type2 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the copy constructor you explicitly define for `sample` doesn't ask for `core`'s copy constructor to be invoked. You'd have to write `: core(obj)` if you wanted to make that happen.

Put another way, when you write an explicit copy constructor, you are taking charge of the copy construction of `sample`, including its `core` sub-object. By writing it the way you have done, you have chosen not to initialise the `core` sub-object using `obj`. Since you haven't said how you *do* want it initialised, the compiler just uses `core`'s  default constructor instead, hence the behaviour in the second case you outline.

By contrast, in the first case, the compiler-generated default copy constructor for `sample` does ask for the `core` sub-object to be initialised using `core`'s copy constructor, hence the observed behaviour.

Comment: I understand that. But what is the motivation for this difference in behavior. Why could not Type1 and Type2 behave the same way?

Comment: Consider the case where you might not want the `core` sub-object to be initialised using `core`'s copy constructor - this gives you a way to avoid it.

Comment: Perfect!. I understood. +1 for the answer and clarification:)

Comment: The bottom line is, that if you want to replace the default copy constructor in a behaviour-preserving way, then you have to do exactly what it does - which includes correctly initialising the base class sub-object. It's arguable that the flexibility you get from being able to initialise the sub-object in a different way is sometimes more than you need/want, but that's the way the language works :)